# How can I add Indian rupee symbol in google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I want to add Indian Rupee symbol in Google chart. I tried below code:

```
 var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        prefix: '&#8377;'
    });
```

It displayed like this &#8377 **80**. I have spent more time to search and fix. But I couldn't. Any one can find the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript unicode, not HTML unicode:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: "\u8360"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        prefix: '<del>&#2352;</del>'
    });
```

OR

By using css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rupee';
    src: url('rupee_foradian-1-webfont.eot');
    src: local('Ã¢ËœÂº'), url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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)
    format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            prefix: '<span style="font-family:rupee;font-size:20px">R</span>'
        });
```

**[Working jsfiddl](http://jsfiddle.net/f8PmM/33/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 र - &#2352;
 Rs - &#8360;
```

for र symbol

```
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
  {prefix: "&#2352;"});
```

for Rs symbol

```
 var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
  {prefix: "&#8360;"});
```